# Can I span the SD card over IP like a USB device?

Tags: networking, usb, sd-card, pi-zero, raid

My issue is that I have 3 or 4 Raspberry Pis zeros, each with a 400gb sd card but I have a 500gb Bitcoin blockchain to store on it, that is growing very quickly.

In theory, if I partition drive space and mount it as a USB block storage device, and then I could use USB over IP with LVM (or similar).

Whats the best solution to span sd mmc drive space over IP?

PS, its just to host just the blockchain and the service is not exactly critical in nature. Unstable but functional is fine.

Comment: Why don't you do it the other way around (mount a larger remote volume and use that)?

Comment: Because typically any block managers like RAID or disk mirroring mouth to a device and not a directory. I'm not even sure if it will take USB.